# Create a dictionary/list from a CSV file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a sheet like this and I want to group it into dictionary. I already imported and it is in this comma-separated format

```
Accession,A,B,O,K,G,F
3364,+,-,+,-,+,-
3365,-+,-,+,-,+,- 
3366,+,-,-,-,+,+
```

I want to put it like this:

```
{'3364': {'A': '+', 'B': '-', 'O': '+','K': '-', 'G': '+', 'F': '-'}}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do some research on `csv.DictReader`. This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Have you looked at the python docs? The [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) modules should solve your problem easily.

Comment: I am sorry. I have a codding that I tried but I forgot to put it here.

Answer (score 0):

Jon is right, but here is a hint:

```
d = {}
a = '3364,+,-,+,-,+,-'
n, *pm = a.split(',')
d[n] = {chr(i+65): v for i, v in enumerate(pm)}
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with Python 3.4

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

a_dict = {}

with open('csv_data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    header = csvreader.__next__()
    header_keys = header[1:]
    for row in csvreader:
        a_dict[row[0]] = {}
        key_value = list(zip(header_keys, row[1:]))
        a_dict[row[0]].update(key_value)

pprint(a_dict)
```